# List only first lines of the command output if pattern matches

Tags: bash

I'm trying to find only accounts ID's of an App from command output that shows a big list of account details.. few account detail output is given below..

Sample Command & its output..

## vaultctrl --show --type=storage

```
 e2158-1234
    description = 'storage_ASDFGHJ'
    enabled = True
    internal.created = 1586282282.590337
    internal.messages = []
    internal.modified = 1586282282.590337
    internal.secondary = True
    internal.store = '__primary__'
    internal.valid = True
    label = 'storage_AKIAWUSH5'
    types = ['storage']

e2158-4567
    description = 'db_dsddssdsade'
    enabled = True
    internal.created = 1586282282.590337
    internal.messages = []
    internal.modified = 1586282282.590337
    internal.secondary = True
    internal.store = '__primary__'
    internal.valid = True
    label = 'db_dsddssdsade'
    types = ['storage']

e2158-7890
    description = 'storage_eegwewqege'
    enabled = True
    internal.created = 1586282282.590337
    internal.messages = []
    internal.modified = 1586282282.590337
    internal.secondary = True
    internal.store = '__primary__'
    internal.valid = True
    label = 'storage_eegwewqege'
    types = ['storage']
```

I would like to list only first lines of these Account Details only if the label of the account has "stoarge_" text in it..

For e.g...

```
    e2158-1234

    
    e2158-7890
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipe your command to

```
awk '!/=/{h=$0;f=1};/storage_/&&f{print h;f=0}'
```

- `!/=/{h=$0;f=1}` checks if line has any `=` sign. If not, save that line to `h` and set `f=1`.
- `/storage_/&&f{print h;f=0}` checks if line contains `storage_` and if `f` is set. If yes, prints the header `h` and unsets `f`.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v FS='\n' -v RS='\n\n' '$10 ~ /storage/ {print $1}' file
```

That uses a double newline to separate "records" and newline to separate fields. It appears that each record has the same number of fields, and "label" is the 10th.

Comment: Thanks Quasímodo & Glenn for your quick help, both answers worked just fine.